# Nginx - Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: nginx, cors

We are getting this error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://stats.g.doubleclick.net
```

In our nginx configuration we have:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN always;
add_header X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff always;
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';" always;
add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade";
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
```

Not sure for the directive and its syntax on how to only allow `doubleclick.net` and our own domain.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a `location` (with a `proxy_pass` directive for example) you can generate the correct headers dynamically:

```
        if ($http_origin ~ '^(?:https?://)?(?:[a-z0-9_.-]+\.)?(?:doubleclick\.net|example\.com)$')
        {
            more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin';
            more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS, POST';
        }
```

Please ask if you don't understand the regex stuff.

You can replace `more_set_headers` with `add_header` if you don't have Ubuntu `nginx-extras` for example. Note the slightly different syntax.

This solution is secure enough for that purpose. It is not so easy to fake the origin header in a standard browser as far as I know. With `curl` you can (test it):

```
curl -H 'Origin: https://example.com' -I -L 'https://example.com' 2>/dev/null | grep -i access-control
```

And:

```
curl -H 'Origin: https://stats.g.doubleclick.net' -I -L 'https://example.com' 2>/dev/null | grep -i access-control
```

Both should return two `access-control` headers. Untested.